# Is there a way to get/create unique id per device per developer on Android? (1 unique device id value for 2 apps associated to the same developer)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, uniqueidentifier

I'm working on 2 video games built using the Unity3D game engine (game-1 and game-2).

For iOS, I used [advertisingIdentifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/adsupport/asidentifiermanager/1614151-advertisingidentifier) which holds the same value across all the apps developed by the same developer. In other words, the advertisingIdentifier variable in game-1 holds the exact value stored in the advertisingIdentifier variable in game-2.

I use this unique id per device for different features. For example, I limit the user's account to be logged in to up to 3 different devices only but the user can log in to unlimited games on the same account (game-1, game-2, game-3...)

For Android, I didn't find any similar Identifier. I tried to use uuid which turned out to be unique per app (game-1 and game-2 installed on the same device don't have the same uuid). I also tried to use MAC addresses which weren't stable at all, some devices support it but not all devices.

Is there any solution to this problem? Even if it depends on a cloud service (Firebase for example) or anything similar, it's fine.

Comment: Seems you can use App set ID. Did you find any other solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't find any way of doing it. There are ways like using MAC addresses or things like this but this is not reliable also it might be illegal.
I think Google did this on purpose to protect users privacy